# Stream Intel RealSense camera to network using Raspberry Pi 4 with FFMpeg

Tags: raspberry-pi, video, ffmpeg, streaming, video-encoding

Good day all

So I have trying to stream my Intel Realsense D435 camera to my local network.

After reading up on many different sites, tutorials, etc I figured out the following:

**What can I do with FFMpeg:**

I can stream to my network using ffmpeg, and I can take advantage of the hardware decoder using h264_mmal provided by the x264 library in ffmpeg.(will explain in more detail later).

Previously I was able to stream my camera using ffmpeg and libx264 encoder/decoder, it was said since this is software base, it will most likely cause a delay, thus I followed a tutorial in getting my `h264_mmal` & `h264_omx` libraries installed for ffmpeg, see [this](https://pastebin.com/ci3KVqRc) ffmpeg setup script [adapted from this](https://retroresolution.com/compiling-ffmpeg-from-source-code-all-in-one-script/) and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/5677qw/hardware_accelerated_x264_encoding_with_ffmpeg/). My script simply adds:

```
  --enable-omx \
  --enable-mmal \
  --enable-omx-rpi \
```

to the ffmpeg configuration.

**The problem is:**

when using the following:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -c:v h264_mmal -pix_fmt yuv420p -i /dev/video4 -s 1280x720 -r 30 -c:v h264_omx -b:v 4000k -f mpegts udp://0.0.0.0:5000
```

recommended [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/5677qw/hardware_accelerated_x264_encoding_with_ffmpeg/) and [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=194868) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1222713/how-to-use-h264-omx-on-raspberrypi) and [here](https://emby.media/community/index.php?/topic/36227-h264-omx-instead-of-x264/page-3) , I get the error:

> [video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x1be1210] Cannot find a proper format for codec
>   'h264' (id 27), pixel format 'yuv420p' (id 0) Assertion *codec_id !=
>   AV_CODEC_ID_NONE failed at src/libavdevice/v4l2.c:811

after playing around, I was able to get a stream running with good spec / quality, but this ends up with CPU ~45% usage and a stream delay of +/-5s. **This delay IS a big deal!**

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video4 -s 1280x720 -r 60 -b:v 4000k -f mpegts udp://0.0.0.0:5000
```

**Configuration:**

```
  libavutil      56. 38.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 66.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 35.104 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 71.100 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video4':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1223.259868, bitrate: 55296 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 320x180, 55296 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> mpeg2video (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mpegts, to 'udp://0.0.0.0:5000':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (4:2:2), yuv422p, 1280x720, q=2-31, 4000 kb/s, 60 fps, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.66.100 mpeg2video
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/4000000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=   85 fps= 30 q=7.3 Lsize=    1292kB time=00:00:02.76 bitrate=3827.0kbits/s speed=0.962x    
video:1188kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 8.771708%
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

what really bugs me is when I open VLC > Media > Open Capture Device > Select /dev/video4 (camera stream), I get a almost 0 delay on my stream - **[Goal] I am trying to replicate this using ffmpeg**.

Doing the same by opening `udp://0.0.0.0:5000` in vlc on my ffmpeg stream gives this 5s delay which is really annoying.

So a couple of issues are raised, but primarily, why do I get the 'Cannot find proper format for codec' issue when trying to stream from my camera device.

As an alternative question, what causes this 5s delay in my ffmpeg stream?

---

**Possible questions you may ask:**

- Why am I using h264?

*This was the first encoder/decoder I found on a stream solution, and kept popping up in questions, if you have an alternative, I am all ears.*

- What did I try to remove this delay?

*I read that since I was using a software encoder `libx264`, I should try hardware encoding thus, my problem above.*

*Also, I tried with various combinations using `-analyzeduration 0`, `-fpsprobesize 32` and `-probesize 32`. Admitedly, I don't fully understand its functions or implications on the stream*

- Do I have the hardware encoding libraries installed?

*see below*

- What is the camera ffprobe output?

  ```
  ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams /dev/video4
  {
      "streams": [
          {
              "index": 0,
              "codec_name": "rawvideo",
              "codec_long_name": "raw video",
              "codec_type": "video",
              "codec_time_base": "1/90",
              "codec_tag_string": "UYVY",
              "codec_tag": "0x59565955",
              "width": 256,
              "height": 144,
              "coded_width": 256,
              "coded_height": 144,
              "has_b_frames": 0,
              "pix_fmt": "uyvy422",
              "level": -99,
              "refs": 1,
              "r_frame_rate": "90/1",
              "avg_frame_rate": "90/1",
              "time_base": "1/1000000",
              "start_pts": 2981098662,
              "start_time": "2981.098662",
              "bit_rate": "53084160", (rest omitted for brevity)
          }
      ],
      "format": {
          "filename": "/dev/video4",
          "nb_streams": 1,
          "nb_programs": 0,
          "format_name": "video4linux2,v4l2",
          "format_long_name": "Video4Linux2 device grab",
          "start_time": "2981.098662",
          "bit_rate": "53084160",
          "probe_score": 99
      }
  }
  ```
- Ok, what about `v4l2-ctl`

  ```
  v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video4 --list-formats
  ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
      Type: Video Capture

      [0]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
      [1]: '' (36315752-1a66-a242-9065-d01814a)
  ```
- Does the camera actually support 1280x720

  *Yes, don't remember the command to list he possible stream resolutions (if someone can leave a comment, will provide the output)*

---

**Further Information:**

**FFMpeg h264 encoders**

```
ffmpeg -encoders | grep h264
ffmpeg version N-96431-g4de2106 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1)
  configuration: --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags='-fPIC -I/root/ffmpeg_build/include' --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-omx --enable-mmal --enable-omx-rpi --enable-nonfree --enable-pic --extra-ldexeflags=-pie --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avutil      configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1+rpt1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --arch=arm --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1+rpt1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --arch=arm --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  avformat    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1+rpt1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --arch=arm --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  avdevice    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1+rpt1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --arch=arm --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  avfilter    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1+rpt1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --arch=arm --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  swscale     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1+rpt1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --arch=arm --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  swresample  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1+rpt1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --arch=arm --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  postproc    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1+rpt1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --arch=arm --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 38.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 66.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 35.104 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 71.100 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  3.100
 V..... libx264              libx264 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (codec h264)
 V..... libx264rgb           libx264 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 RGB (codec h264)
 V..... h264_omx             OpenMAX IL H.264 video encoder (codec h264)
 V..... h264_v4l2m2m         V4L2 mem2mem H.264 encoder wrapper (codec h264)
 V..... h264_vaapi           H.264/AVC (VAAPI) (codec h264)
```

**FFMpeg h264 decoders**

```
ffmpeg -decoders | grep h264
ffmpeg version N-96431-g4de2106 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1)
  configuration: --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags='-fPIC -I/root/ffmpeg_build/include' --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-omx --enable-mmal --enable-omx-rpi --enable-nonfree --enable-pic --extra-ldexeflags=-pie --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avutil      configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1+rpt1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --arch=arm --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1+rpt1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --arch=arm --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  avformat    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1+rpt1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --arch=arm --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  avdevice    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1+rpt1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --arch=arm --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  avfilter    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1+rpt1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --arch=arm --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  swscale     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1+rpt1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --arch=arm --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  swresample  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1+rpt1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --arch=arm --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  postproc    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1+rpt1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --arch=arm --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 38.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 66.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 35.104 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 71.100 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  3.100
 VFS..D h264                 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
 V..... h264_v4l2m2m         V4L2 mem2mem H.264 decoder wrapper (codec h264)
 V..... h264_mmal            h264 (mmal) (codec h264)
```

Comment: I was in need of a low-latency stream, too. I never managed to minimize buffering with ffmpeg. I ended up writing my own server. It transmits MJPEG over HTTP at only one frame delay. It already supports an older model of the Realsense camera. You can probably use it right away if you compile it against a more recent version of librealsense than I did. Maybe it is a viable alternative for you. https://github.com/fhwedel-hoe/lazy_mjpeg_streamer

Comment: @Hermann this looks promising. How did you handle the depth/infrared camera? Is that an option for streaming too?

Comment: I was not interested in the depth information. It is mentioned in the code, but commented out. You'd need to pass `TJPF_GRAY` to the compressor. I had the camera running at 5 FPS so I never ran into any problems regarding to performance. If you need all 30 FPS, you might need to look into https://github.com/hopkinskong/rpi-omx-jpeg-encode or https://github.com/jtanx/omxcv, which – now that I think about it – might not be worth the hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Intel provides a software to utilize a RPi4 as backend, to make your camera available in your network and directly use all API commands: https://dev.intelrealsense.com/docs/open-source-ethernet-networking-for-intel-realsense-depth-cameras

FRAMOS has a similar middleware for their reference models:
[image]
**D435_Manual_V1.1 - Page 24**

https://www.framos.com/en/framos-depth-camera-d435e-camera-only-22806